# Android Save Login Facebook Information into Mysql Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I've already success with Facebook login. How to save facebook user information into database mysql like name & email?

Answer (score 0):

Check this for mysql connection; https://gist.github.com/cofearabi/5039135

Answer (score 0):

You can access Facebook username with Facebook graph api

Explore Facebook graph api from the link below

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph